# Read JSON date from file

Tags: c#, json

I write my logs to a text file as JSON. In the file the call obejct LogTime value is

```
"1378289277591".
*{"LogTime":"Date(1378290565240)"}*
```

Consider the code below:

```
Public Class Sync{
  public async Task<CallModel> ConvertCallFileToCallObejct(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    string callText = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    var call = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CallModel>(callText);

                    return call;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

I convert the Call File to Call Object:

```
var sync = new Sync();
CallModel call = sync.ConvertCallFileToCallObejct(e.FullPath).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The problem is that `Call.LogTime` is **9/4/2013 10:29:25 AM** but Using Chrome Console and new Date(1378290565240) the result is  **9/4/2013 14:59:25 PM**

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Maybe the time is in UTC?

Comment: what is your timezone?

Comment: Iran time zone is UTC+3:50 right?

Comment: actually, during daylight saving time, Iran is UTC+4:30, and 9/4 falls under DST, this is exactly the difference.

Comment: I guess that Chrome and your C# code treat it differently. What does `Call.LogTime.Kind` return? I guess `Utc`?

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
// JSON received from server is in string format
var jsonString = '{"date":1251877601000}';

//use JSON2 or some JS library to parse the string
var jsonObject =  JSON.parse( jsonString );

//now you have your date!
alert( new Date(jsonObject.date) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your Time zone is but I would expect that its UTC datetime.

Answer (score 1):

According to your profile, you live in Iran, where the timezone is UTC+3:30. However, in April, Iran uses daylight saving time so the real timezone is UTC+4:30.

This means that UTC time of `9/4/2013 10:29:25 AM` is `9/4/2013 14:59:25 PM` local time in Iran.

According to [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9), the time given in your JSON string is treated as UTC time, and it is deserialized as such. You can check the return value of `Call.LogTime` expression which returns `DateTimeKind.Utc`. Thus, what you see in your C# code is UTC time.

Now, Chrome also sees this time as UTC time, however it seems to display it as local time, according to your timezone. I am not 100% sure, but I think that Chrome uses your list of preferred languages when choosing how to display date, so try to play with it - I have no idea what exactly it does, but I remember a similar problem when changing the language order affected how time was interpreted. OF course, it depends on what exactly you try to achieve - IMO, both values are correct, as it is the same time.